# Python calculate factorial, OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, factorial

I want to write a function that calculate (1 / n!) * (1! + 2! + 3! + ... + n!) with n as the parameter of the function, also the result is truncated to 6 decimals (not rounded).
Below is my code:

```
def going(n):
    n1 = n 
    n2 = n
    factorial = 1
    back = 1
    for i in range(2, n1+1):
        factorial *= i
    while n2>1:
        this = 1
        for i in range(2, n2+1):
            this*=i
        back+=this
        n2 = n2-1
        this = 1
    result = int((1/factorial)*back*1000000)/1000000
    return result
```

When I passed the argument 171 into the function, I got the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/going.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(going(171))
  File "/Users/Desktop/going.py", line 15, in going
    result = int((1/factorial)*back*1000000)/1000000
OverflowError: int too large to convert to float
```

How can I fix this problem? Thanks a lot for help!

--update--
Sorry that I didn't clarify: I'm doing this problem in Codewars and I don't think I can import any libraries to use. So, I need a solution that can avoid using any libraries.

Original problem from Codewars:

Consider the following numbers (where n! is factorial(n)):

```
u1 = (1 / 1!) * (1!)
u2 = (1 / 2!) * (1! + 2!)
u3 = (1 / 3!) * (1! + 2! + 3!)
un = (1 / n!) * (1! + 2! + 3! + ... + n!)
```

Which will win: 1 / n! or (1! + 2! + 3! + ... + n!)?

Are these numbers going to 0 because of 1/n! or to infinity due to the sum of factorials?

**Task**

Calculate (1 / n!) * (1! + 2! + 3! + ... + n!) for a given n, where n is an integer greater or equal to 1.

To avoid discussions about rounding, return the result truncated to 6 decimal places, for example:

1.0000989217538616 will be truncated to 1.000098
1.2125000000000001 will be truncated to 1.2125

**Remark**

Keep in mind that factorials grow rather rapidly, and you need to handle large inputs.

Comment: Try in the IRB `2**9999` vs `float(2**9999)`

Comment: can u post original and full problem from codewars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@PaSTE's suggestion to use gmpy2 is great, and should work fine.

The library [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) is built on top of gmpy2 and provides the function `ff` (falling factorial) that makes the implementation a little more concise:

```
import mpmath

def going_mp(n):
    return sum([1/mpmath.ff(n, k) for k in range(n)])
```

For example,

```
In [54]: import mpmath

In [55]: mpmath.mp.dps = 30

In [56]: going_mp(170)
Out[56]: mpf('1.00591736819491744725806951204519')

In [57]: going_mp(171)
Out[57]: mpf('1.00588255770874220729390683925161')
```

(I left out the truncating of the digits.  That's something that you can add as you see fit.)

---

Another standard technique for handling very large numbers is to work with the *logarithms* of the numbers instead of the numbers themselves.  In this case, you can use [`math.lgamma`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.lgamma) to compute `k!/n!` as `exp(lgamma(k+1) - lgamma(n+1))`.  This will allow you to compute the value using just the standard `math` library.

```
import math

def going_l(n):
    lognfac = math.lgamma(n + 1)
    return sum([math.exp(math.lgamma(k+1) - lognfac) for k in range(1, n+1)])
```

For example,

```
In [69]: going_l(170)
Out[69]: 1.0059173681949172

In [70]: going_l(171)
Out[70]: 1.0058825577087422
```

---

Finally, if you don't want to use even the standard library, you could avoid the large numbers another way.  Rewrite the expression as

```
       1      1           1                 1
   1 + - + ------- + ------------- + ... + ---
       n   n*(n-1)   n*(n-1)*(n-2)          n!
```

That leads to this implementation:

```
def going_nolibs(n):
    total = 0.0
    term = 1.0
    for k in range(n, 0, -1):
        total += term
        term /= k
    return total
```

For example,

```
In [112]: going_nolibs(170)
Out[112]: 1.0059173681949174

In [113]: going_nolibs(171)
Out[113]: 1.0058825577087422
```

Answer (score 4):

And `going(170)` works as intended, right?

What you are seeing is a fundamental limitation of how your computer represents floating point numbers, and not a problem with Python *per se*.  In general, most modern computers use  [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) to represent and perform math with non-integer numbers.  Specifically, numbers using IEEE 754's ["binary64" (double-precision)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) floating point representation has a maximum value of 2^1023 × (1 + (1 − 2^−52)), or approximately 1.7976931348623157 × 10^308.  It turns out that 170! ≈ 7.2 × 10^306, which is just under the maximum value.  However, 171! ≈ 1.2 × 10^309, so you are out of luck.

The best chance you have of actually performing calculations with numbers that large without running into these overflow errors or losing precision is to use a large number library like [gmpy2](https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy) (see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386604/handling-big-numbers-in-code)).  A possible solution would be:

```
from gmpy2 import mpz, add, div, fac
def going(n):
    factorial = fac(n)
    back = mpz(1)
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        back = add(back, fac(i))
    result = div(back, factorial)
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm doing this problem in Codewars and I don't think I can import any libraries, do you have any other solutions?