# how python stores value for very very large integers

Tags: python, largenumber

Look at this simple python program

```
def fib1(n):
a, b = 0, 1
while b < n :
    print b,
    a, b = b, a+b

if __name__ == '__main__':
import sys
fib1(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

If run this code as

```
python fibo.py 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Snippet of Output:

```
1303467741340483121659023383282949754951354892487032836821556660754115695648928602663356832403903120316774306 2109055108727958115216736026700200421586510355834736601003381505407930071607408184616335724173657853423941515 3412522850068441236875759409983150176537865248321769437824938166162045767256336787279692556577560973740715821 5521577958796399352092495436683350598124375604156506038828319671569975838863744971896028280751218827164657336 8934100808864840588968254846666500774662240852478275476653257837732021606120081759175720837328779800905373157 14455678767661239941060750283349851372786616456634781515481577509301997444983826731071749118079998628070030493 23389779576526080530029005130016352147448857309113056992134835347034019051103908490247469955408778428975403650 37845458344187320471089755413366203520235473765747838507616412856336016496087735221319219073488777057045434143 61235237920713401001118760543382555667684331074860895499751248203370035547191643711566689028897555486020837793 99080696264900721472208515956748759187919804840608734007367661059706052043279378932885908102386332543066271936 160315934185614122473327276500131314855604135915469629507118909263076087590471022644452597131283888029087109729 259396630450514843945535792456880074043523940756078363514486570322782139633750401577338505233670220572153381665 419712564636128966418863068957011388899128076671547993021605479585858227224221424221791102364954108601240491394 679109195086643810364398861413891462942652017427626356536092049908640366857971825799129607598624329173393873059 1098821759722772776783261930370902851841780094099174349557697529494498594082193250020920709963578437774634364453 1777930954809416587147660791784794314784432111526800706093789579403138960940165075820050317562202766948028237512 2876752714532189363930922722155697166626212205625975055651487108897637555022358325840971027525781204722662601965 4654683669341605951078583513940491481410644317152775761745276688300776515962523401661021345087983971670690839477 7531436383873795315009506236096188648036856522778750817396763797198414070984881727501992372613765176393353441442 12186120053215401266088089750036680129447500839931526579142040485499190586947405129163013717701749148064044280919 19717556437089196581097595986132868777484357362710277396538804282697604657932286856665006090315514324457397722361 31903676490304597847185685736169548906931858202641803975680844768196795244879691985828019808017263472521442003280 51621232927393794428283281722302417684416215565352081372219649050894399902811978842493025898332777796978839725641 83524909417698392275468967458471966591348073767993885347900493819091195147691670828321045706350041269500281728921 135146142345092186703752249180774384275764289333345966720120142869985595050503649670814071604682819066479121454562 218671051762790578979221216639246350867112363101339852068020636689076790198195320499135117311032860335979403183483 353817194107882765682973465820020735142876652434685818788140779559062385248698970169949188915715679402458524638045 572488245870673344662194682459267086009989015536025670856161416248139175446894290669084306226748539738437927821528 926305439978556110345168148279287821152865667970711489644302195807201560695593260839033495142464219140896452459573 1498793685849229455007362830738554907162854683506737160500463612055340736142487551508117801369212758879334380281101 2425099125827785565352530979017842728315720351477448650144765807862542296838080812347151296511676978020230832740674 3923892811677015020359893809756397635478575034984185810645229419917883032980568363855269097880889736899565213021775 6348991937504800585712424788774240363794295386461634460789995227780425329818649176202420394392566714919796045762449 10272884749181815606072318598530637999272870421445820271435224647698308362799217540057689492273456451819361258784224 16621876686686616191784743387304878363067165807907454732225219875478733692617866716260109886666023166739157304546673 26894761435868431797857061985835516362340036229353275003660444523177042055417084256317799378939479618558518563330897 43516638122555047989641805373140394725407202037260729735885664398655775748034950972577909265605502785297675867877570 70411399558423479787498867358975911087747238266614004739546108921832817803452035228895708644544982403856194431208467 113928037680978527777140672732116305813154440303874734475431773320488593551486986201473617910150485189153870299086037 184339437239402007564639540091092216900901678570488739214977882242321411354939021430369326554695467593010064730294504 298267474920380535341780212823208522714056118874363473690409655562810004906426007631842944464845952782163935029380541 482606912159782542906419752914300739614957797444852212905387537805131416261365029062212271019541420375173999759675045 780874387080163078248199965737509262329013916319215686595797193367941421167791036694055215484387373157337934789055586 1263481299239945621154619718651810001943971713764067899501184731173072837429156065756267486503928793532511934548730631 2044355686320108699402819684389319264272985630083283586096981924541014258596947102450322701988316166689849869337786217 3307836985560054320557439403041129266216957343847351485598166655714087096026103168206590188492244960222361803886516848 5352192671880163019960259087430448530489942973930635071695148580255101354623050270656912890480561126912211673224303065 8660029657440217340517698490471577796706900317777986557293315235969188450649153438863503078972806087134573477110819913 14012222329320380360477957577902026327196843291708621628988463816224289805272203709520415969453367214046785150335122978 22672251986760597700995656068373604123903743609486608186281779052193478255921357148383919048426173301181358627445942891 36684474316080978061473613646275630451100586901195229815270242868417768061193560857904335017879540515228143777781065869 59356726302841575762469269714649234575004330510681838001552021920611246317114918006288254066305713816409502405227008760 96041200618922553823942883360924865026104917411877067816822264789029014378308478864192589084185254331637646183008074629 155397926921764129586412153075574099601109247922558905818374286709640260695423396870480843150490968148047148588235083389 251439127540686683410355036436498964627214165334435973635196551498669275073731875734673432234676222479684794771243158018 406837054462450812996767189512073064228323413256994879453570838208309535769155272605154275385167190627731943359478241407 658276182003137496407122225948572028855537578591430853088767389706978810842887148339827707619843413107416738130721399425 1065113236465588309403889415460645093083860991848425732542338227915288346612042420944981983005010603735148681490199640832 1723389418468725805811011641409217121939398570439856585631105617622267157454929569284809690624854016842565419620921040257 2788502654934314115214901056869862215023259562288282318173443845537555504066971990229791673629864620577714101111120681089 4511892073403039921025912698279079336962658132728138903804549463159822661521901559514601364254718637420279520732041721346 7300394728337354036240813755148941551985917695016421221977993308697378165588873549744393037884583257997993621843162402435 11812286801740393957266726453428020888948575827744560125782542771857200827110775109258994402139301895418273142575204123781 19112681530077747993507540208576962440934493522760981347760536080554578992699648659003387440023885153416266764418366526216 30924968331818141950774266662004983329883069350505541473543078852411779819810423768262381842163187048834539906993570649997 50037649861895889944281806870581945770817562873266522821303614932966358812510072427265769282187072202250806671411937176213 80962618193714031895056073532586929100700632223772064294846693785378138632320496195528151124350259251085346578405507826210 131000268055609921839337880403168874871518195097038587116150308718344497444830568622793920406537331453336153249817445002423 211962886249323953734393953935755803972218827320810651410997002503722636077151064818322071530887590704421499828222952828633 342963154304933875573731834338924678843737022417849238527147311222067133521981633441115991937424922157757653078040397831056 554926040554257829308125788274680482815955849738659889938144313725789769599132698259438063468312512862179152906263350659689 897889194859191704881857622613605161659692872156509128465291624947856903121114331700554055405737435019936805984303748490745
```

Now my question is, how python manages to store such a large numbers?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: You can find the source for CPython under [`Objects/longobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bf98400daa62/Objects/longobject.c).

Comment: Very nice explanation under https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2bbbvk/how_does_python_handle_bignum_arithmetic/

Comment: I also found that [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538551/handling-very-large-numbers-in-python) explained it really well, including how / why Python does this automatically for you.

Comment: The relevant PEP: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/

Answer (score 1):

In the form of an answer...

In effect, because lists, strings etc can be basically any size, subject to available memory constraints, it was decided to extend that functionality to integers.

The second of two implementations was taken, with the upshot being ([From the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/), as indicated by others):

> The existing short and long int types remain, but operations
>          return a long int instead of raising OverflowError when a
>          result cannot be represented as a short int.  A new type,
>          integer, may be introduced that is an abstract base type of
>          which both the int and long implementation types are
>          subclassed.  This is useful so that programs can check
>          integer-ness with a single test:
>
> if isinstance(i, integer): ...
>
> After some consideration, the second implementation plan was
>       selected, since it is far easier to implement, is backwards
>       compatible at the C API level, and in addition can be implemented
>       partially as a transitional measure.

It's worth noting the difference between how integers are treated and [how floats are treated, which result in OverflowError much earlier.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201706/overflowerror-34-result-too-large)