# OverflowError when subclassing rv_continuous

Tags: python-3.x

```
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np  # generic math functions


# https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1658
class LorentzGen(st.rv_continuous):
    """Lorentz distribution"""

    def _pdf(self, x):
        gamma = 0.27
        return 2 * gamma / (np.pi * (gamma ** 2 + x ** 2))


transverse_fields = LorentzGen(a=0)
gaussian_gen = st.norm()

L = 2

list_of_temps = np.linspace(1, 10, 40)

for T, temp in enumerate(list_of_temps):
    print(f"Run {T}")
    for t in range(5000):
        if t%500==0:
            print(f"Trial {t}")
        h_x = [[-transverse_fields.rvs(), xx] for xx in range(L)]  # OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
        # h_y = [[-gaussian_gen.rvs(), xx] for xx in range(L)]  # Works
```

In the above code, I have implemented my own probability distribution (essentially a half Lorentzian, x∈[0,∞]), modified from the answer from [scicomp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1658), which I call `transverse_fields`.

I need to generate a whole bunch of values from this `transverse_fields`, using them in a nested For loop. The issue is that beyond a certain number of runs, here "Run 1 Trial ~3500", I get a bunch of errors:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py:385: IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent.
  warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2831: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ? (vectorized)
  outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/<redacted>/stackoverflow.py", line 26, in <module>
    h_x = [[-transverse_fields.rvs(), xx] for xx in range(L)]  # Result Overflow
  File "C:/<redacted>/stackoverflow.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    h_x = [[-transverse_fields.rvs(), xx] for xx in range(L)]  # Result Overflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 954, in rvs
    vals = self._rvs(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 889, in _rvs
    Y = self._ppf(U, *args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 902, in _ppf
    return self._ppfvec(q, *args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2755, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2831, in _vectorize_call
    outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1587, in _ppf_single
    while self._ppf_to_solve(right, q, *args) < 0.:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1569, in _ppf_to_solve
    return self.cdf(*(x, )+args)-q
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1745, in cdf
    place(output, cond, self._cdf(*goodargs))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1621, in _cdf
    return self._cdfvec(x, *args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2755, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2831, in _vectorize_call
    outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1618, in _cdf_single
    return integrate.quad(self._pdf, self.a, x, args=args)[0]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 341, in quad
    points)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 448, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
  File "C:/<redacted>/stackoverflow.py", line 11, in _pdf
    return 2 * gamma / (np.pi * (gamma ** 2 + x ** 2))
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Note that the error does not occur if I bump the number of trials, here `t` to a smaller number like 50, nor does it occur if `list_of_temps` has less values, e.g. `np.linspace(1,10,4)`. **Even though** in the original problem, with `np.linspace(1,10,40)`, the error popped up during Run 1.

With the original setup, there is also no overflow error when I use the standard Gaussian distribution function from `scipy.stats`.

[Similar issues on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20201706/8421052) that I've seen attribute this to the range over which the for loop is run is too big. But I don't quite see that here? And I don't quite understand how to implement Decimal as suggested in the answer in the linked question, in any case.

How can I fix this?

I'm running Python 3.6.5 with Anaconda on 64bit Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the way I'm declaring my probability distribution with `transverse_fields`/`LorentzGen`.

My solution was to use the in-built `cauchy` distribution in `scipy.stats`, with a modified scale. 
Also since I wanted a half-Lorentzian, I just took the absolute `np.abs(...)` when drawing a random number from `transverse_fields`.

```
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np  # generic math functions

transverse_fields = st.cauchy(scale=0.27)
L = 2

list_of_temps = np.linspace(1, 10, 40)

for T, temp in enumerate(list_of_temps):
    print(f"Run {T}")
    for t in range(5000):
        if t%500==0:
            print(f"Trial {t}")
        h_x = [[-np.abs(transverse_fields.rvs()), xx] for xx in range(L)]  # Now works
```

This is satisfactory enough for me now, but I would still appreciate someone explaining why my way of subclassing `rv_continuous` gave me the aforementioned errors.