# Is this a case that I should use the decimal library?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = 1.5
i = 0
k = 0.2
results = []

while True:

    i += 1
    results.append(k)

    if k < a**i:
        continue

    elif k > a**i and k < 2 * a**1:
        k = k - a**i

    elif k > 2 * a**i:
        k = k - 2 * a**i

    else:
        break


print(results)
```

This is a python code to solve a real-life math problem. When I ran it, terminal gave a traceback like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fusing.py", line 11, in <module>
    if k < a**i:
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201706/overflowerror-34-result-too-large) on stack overflow about the error. The accepted answer says that the OP can use the decimal library to fix it. I'm not sure whether I should use it or there are some other solutions to it. I'd be grateful if someone can tell me what to do.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it not work?

Comment: Ok, But when you fix the error it will take still pretty long time to run tho

Comment: Well, I will try it. Just wondering if this is the best way and if there are other solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are in an infinite loop - k will always be smaller than 1.5 in the power of i > 1.
So you keep adding items (k) to results till it overflows.

Comment: Ahhh! a was supposed to be (2/3). How stupid of me to make such an obvious mistake! Thanks!