# Python overflow when calculating Gaussian function

Tags: python, math, gaussian

I am trying to calculate the value of the Gaussian function using the following definition

```
from math import e

def function(x):
    return 100 / (e**((x-2000)**2))**1/16
```

But I am getting an overflow with values of 20000, 30000, 1000000, etc.
Do you know a workaround
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201706/overflowerror-34-result-too-large)

Comment: `e**(500)` is `1.4035922178528e+217`. How could you possibly need `e**(18000)`, let alone squaring the exponent and using even higher exponents?

Comment: Just think about it - `x = 20000 => (x-2000)^2 = 324000000` and then you calculate `e^324000000`. No wonder you get an overflow...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201706/overflowerror-34-result-too-large

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `math.exp`:

   ```
   100 / math.exp((x-2000)**2))**1/16
   ```

   This is more performant and numerically accurate than `e**`.
2. Note that `...**1/16` probably doesn't do what you want. `**` has [higher operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `/`, so the above is equivalent to `(...**1)/16`. Wrap the fraction in parentheses:

   ```
   100 / math.exp((x-2000)**2)**(1/16.0)
   ```

   Writing `16` in floating point format (`16.0`) to prevent integer division.
3. Use exponent rules to incorporate the `1/16`:

   ```
   100 / math.exp((x-2000)**2/16.0)
   ```

   This reduces large arguments, which helps to improve precision.
4. Flip the sign of the argument and change the division to a multiplication:

   ```
   100 * math.exp(-(x-2000)**2/16.0)
   ```

   This will underflow instead of overflow in extreme cases. Underflows are much more well-behaved in this situation – you'll just get zero instead of an `OverflowError`.

Comment: I'd recommend changing 2/16 to 0.125 if the complier isn't doing it for you.

Comment: @duffymo `**` has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `/`; also would it really help (performance or accuracy -wise) to do this?

Comment: No one will notice any performance issues.  I worry about integer versus floating point division.  When I enter 2/16 into my Python REPL it returns zero instead of 1/8 = 0.125.  Looks like I have Python 2.7.15 running.

Comment: @duffymo you are right, thanks for the catch; I assumed that `**` would perform a conversion to floating point.

Comment: I'm glad to help.  Edit your answer.

Comment: @duffymo your edit produces different results because `**` has higher precedence than `/` – i.e. `(x - 2000)**2/16 == ((x - 2000)**2)/16 != (x-2000)**(2/16)`. Also changing the denominator to `16.0` works too (and the value of the standard deviation is clearer when written in this way).

Comment: Minor nitpicking: instead of "performant", say "faster" or "uses less memory" or whatever specific behavior you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to rework the formula by taking the logarithm of it (i.e. convert the formula with the product of terms into the sum of the logarithm of each term) and then take the exponential of the result.