# OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large') calculate e^-(b*dE)

Tags: python, exponential, largenumber

I want to calculate boltzmann distribution which is `e**-(b*dE)`. `b` is `1/kT` where `k` is boltzmann constant and `T` is temperature. `dE` is delta energy.

I use `from scipy.constants import k` to get the value of `k` and `import math` to get the value of `e`. `dE` and `T` are integer.

Is there any library that can import to get the value of `e^-(b*dE)` easily?

Comment: can you post an example of `b` and `dE`? It "works" for me here: https://repl.it/repls/LeanBlindBusinesssoftware

Comment: example of b : 1.810743258537662e+22. dE is just integer

Comment: that still works for me

Comment: your code is not working when I put dE is minus integer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201706/overflowerror-34-result-too-large)

Comment: Can you provide example input (values for `dE` and `T`) that causes this error? What is the expected result for these input values?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `^` (xor) operator, but `**` (pow):

```
e**-(b*dE)
```

Or:

```
import math
math.exp(-(b*dE))
```