# getting OverflowError in python

Tags: python, overflowexception

I need to express and use the following equation in Python code. However, I am getting an OverflowError when I substitute `X = 340.15` in:

```
Y = [e^(-989)] * (X^171)
```

I did a quick search on Google but was unable to find out how to get the equation running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201706/overflowerror-34-result-too-large)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `decimal.Decimal` to get the equation running:

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal

X = Decimal('340.15')
e = Decimal(math.e)

Y = pow(e, -989) * pow(X, 171)
print(Y)
```

Prints:

```
2502.699307245550715093058647
```

Here is [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28e%5E%28-989%29%29+*+%28340.15%5E171%29) from Wolfram Alpha to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because 340.15 ^ 171 is too large. Even computers have limits