# I'm trying to make a bmi calculator in python and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Tags: python, calculator

This is my **code**

```
weight = float(input("Please Enter Your Weight In KIlograms: "))
height = float(input("Please Enter Your Height In Meters: "))

result = weight / height ** height
print("Your BMI is " + result)
```

And this is the error:

```
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

I'm really not to familiar with the technical terms yet, so you might have to be a little more specific in your explanation.

Comment: If you add parenthesis like `result = (weight / height) ** height`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201706/overflowerror-34-result-too-large

Comment: You mean `height**2` (height squared), not `height**height` (height to the power of height)

Comment: @NathanWride I think it is more likely they meant `weight / (height * height)` (or simply `weight / height**2`)

Comment: @MuhammadJunaidHaris while it is the same error, it is not the same cause and the duplicated question doesn't answer this one...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
height = float(input("Input your height in meters: "))
weight = float(input("Input your weight in kilogram: "))
print("Your body mass index is: ", round(weight / (height * height), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

your code needs some changes. Your final print statement tries concatenate a string and a float ie the string being "Your BMI is " the float being result. So you have to make them both the same type as below. `("Your BMI is " + str(result))`. And also the BMI equation is Weight/Height^2 rather than Weight/ Height^Height. So change the calculation part to `result = weight / height ** 2`.

```
weight = float(input("Please Enter Your Weight In Kilograms: ")) 
height = float(input("Please Enter Your Height In Meters: "))

result = weight / height ** 2 
print("Your BMI is " + str(result))
```