# How do I do exponents if the result gives "OverflowError"?

Tags: python, error-handling

```
def RSA_decrypt(c, d, N):
    num_mesage = (c**d)%N
    return num_mesage

dec = RSA_decrypt(3093, 2458.40206185567, 4559)
print(dec)
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9iti.png)
in RSA_decrypt
num_mesage = (c**d)%N
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

Comment: **result should be 86**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201706/overflowerror-34-result-too-large Does this answer your question?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use floating-point arithmetic here?

Comment: @mkrieger1
If that's the only way to get 86 yes, but if not then no.

Comment: @Ismail Hafeez
I did find this before posting this question but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Another way of getting 86 would be `((c ** int(d)) % N) % 100`.

Comment: Why doesn't the answer to the other question, which suggests to use `Decimal`, help you?

Comment: @mkrieger1
`Decimal` still gives an error

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work if I change the variables:
    `c,d,N = 1004, 9672.034482758621, 3127`
    `num_mesage = ((c ** int(d)) % N)%100`
    `num_mesage = 1`
it should still be 86.

Comment: Even if you were to calculate `(c ** d) % N` with the numbers given in the question, the result is 731.196..., not 86. Why do you think that it should result in 86?

Comment: I have a function that gives me the variables,
this function just decrypts it.
RSA encryption.