# Supress scientific notation without knowing length of number?

Tags: python-3.x

In python, how could I go about supressing scientific notation with complete precision WITHOUT knowing the length of number?

I need python to dynamically be able to return the number in normal form with exact precision no matter how large the number is, and to do it without any trailing zeros. The numbers will always be integers but they will be getting very large and I need them to be completely accurate. Even a single digit being rounded or changed would mess up my program.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. Python supports arbitrary large integers (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538551/handling-very-large-numbers-in-python). So where is the rounding happening?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `decimal` class.

```
Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a user alterable
precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as large as needed for a given
problem.
```

From https://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html

Comment: What if I don't know how much precision I need?