# Handling digits Log and Antilog operation in Python for large numbers (16 digits)

Tags: python

```py
a = math.log(123456789123456789)
b = exp(a)
print(int(round(abs(b))))
```

output:

```
123456789123457168
```

There is data loss after doing anitlog please tell me how to avoid it

Comment: This looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538551/handling-very-large-numbers-in-python. I'd say use a `long` type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Decimal` from `decimal` module to handle large numbers:

```
from decimal import Decimal


a = Decimal(123456789123456789).ln()
b = a.exp()
print(int(round(abs(b))))

Output:

123456789123456789
```

Comment: You can accept this answer if it suits to your needs.