# Calculating very large power

Tags: python, algorithm, math, calculation

I want to calculate for very large numbers like n = 10^15.

Somehow I can't, because of OverflowError.

```
xd = lambda n : ((((5+ sqrt(17)) * ((3 + sqrt(17)) ** n)) - ((5-sqrt(17))* ((3 - sqrt(17)) ** n)))/((2 ** (n+1)) * sqrt(17)))
```

even for n=1000, it wouldn't be calculated.

Though, I should mention that I want the modular of it (1000000007)

What would be the solution?

Comment: google [modpow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214) ... its much faster to do `modpow(a,b,c)` then  `pow(a,b) mod c` because you do not need big numbers ... I saw some people (younger and on newer lanuages like JAVA or python) are using `powmod` name instead however IIRC it should be `modpow` So simply do power by squaring with modular arithmetrics ... just like I did in the linked `modpow` implementation

Comment: @Spektre how about float numbers? in my case, (3 + sqrt(17)) ^ n. Is it also modpow?

Comment: hmm that is  a problem because it depends on what do you consider to be a mod of float?

Comment: you can easily use [power by squaring or log/exp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214) approach on floats and fixed point thge same way as on integers but mod is a special case ... so if you truncate your float to int and thed mod then yes if you use something like fmod then you need to multiply by number you are modulo to truncate to integer and then restore the result somehow ...

Comment: @Spektre I mean, it doesn't need mod, but also I can't calculate very large n for (3 + sqrt(17)) ^ n :-??

Comment: Follow this. Hope it will be effective https://stackoverflow.com/a/538583/5929910

Comment: @toRex Thanks I saw it before, and I use Python 3.8, but my numbers are very very large I think that it can't handle it.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain a bit about the circumstances that lead to this formula, because it seems a bit odd: apparently you want to do modular arithmetic, but there is an (necessarily inexact) square root of 17 in here as well, and 17 is not a quadratic residue modulo 1000000007

Comment: @Spektre Thanks I will search about power by squaring :-?

Comment: @harold it's about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/686374/842598). (Sn)

Comment: the problem is that power function implementation on floats is most likely using log/exp approach and computing that on arbitrary big floats is not easy as LUTs are out of question... if it is ok for the result try to truncate the `(3 + sqrt(17))` into integer `x` and then use `x**n` that should force to use integer power which should be fine ... however I am not coding in python so I do not know for sure how good it is implemented. You can also do do a fixed point computation if you need also few decimal places after dot ...

Comment: @Spektre that would give me the wrong answer (I think)

Comment: @Spektre it's about this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/686374/842598 (The Sn part)

Comment: Use integer arithmetic throughout: you can compute `xd(n)` by finding the `n`th power of the 2-by-2 integer matrix `[[3, 2], [1, 0]]` and multiplying by the vector `[4, 1]` - that gives you `xd(n+1)` together with `xd(n)`. To compute the nth power of the matrix efficiently modulo `1000000007`, use the standard modular exponentiation algorithm (but applied to 2-by-2 integer matrices rather than plain integers).

Comment: @MikeyFreeman OK I recommend using a different mathematical solution, for example based on a matrix power (this is probably possible but I didn't work it out) which would not involve square roots or divisions

Comment: just try if it will overflow ... if not then do something like `a = (x*1000)**n; b =1000**n;`  and then convert to float `y = a/b` which should give you your answer  with limited precision but still better than integers alone ... the `1000` can be enlarged .... to improve accuracy

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks, I think that would be the solution, I will work on it.

Comment: @harold Yeah, I'll work on it. Thanks

Comment: @Spektre I will try it, thank you

Comment: @MarkDickinson Sorry, how did you come up with `[[3, 2], [1, 0]]` or `[4, 1]`?

Comment: @MikeyFreeman: If you express `xd(n+1)` and `xd(n)` in terms of `xd(n)` and `xd(n-1)`, you get the matrix equation: `[xd(n+1), xd(n)] = [[3, 2], [1, 0]] * [xd(n), xd(n-1)]` (awkward to write in a comment - think of the vectors as columns vectors here). The top row of the matrix comes from the recurrence relation `xd(n+1) = 3*xd(n) + 2*xd(n-1)`; the bottom row just gives the identity `xd(n) = 1*xd(n) + 0*xd(n-1)`. The starting vector `[4, 1]` is `[xd(1), xd[0]]`.

Comment: xd(n+1) = xd(n+2) + xd(n+1). This is the Sn (xd=Sn), not the An (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/686374/842598). Or am I wrong?

Comment: @MarkDickinson No, I was wrong, Thanks, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the answer on maths.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686328/combinatorics-on-letters/686374#686374) where the formula comes from, it appears that the easiest thing to calculate are the a(n).

So, this can be calculated by recurence very simply, and this time, as we only use multiplications and additions, we can take advantage of the rules of modulo arithmetic and keep the numbers we manipulate small:

```
def s(n, mod):
    a1 = 1
    a2 = 3
    for k in range(n-1):
        a1, a2 = a2, (3*a2 + 2* a1) % mod
    return (a1 + a2) % mod


mod = 1000000007

print(s(10, mod))
# 363314, as with the other formulas...

print(s(10**6, mod))
# 982192189

%timeit s(10**6, mod)
# 310 ms ± 6.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit s(10**7, mod)
# 3.39 s ± 93.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

We get the same results as with the other formulas, (which is a really good thing...). As the numbers used during the calculation keep the same size, at most 5 times the modulo, the calculation time is about O(n) - `s(10**7)` takes only 10 times more time than `s(10**6)`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct that the solution in terms of `a[n]` is much cleaner than dealing with floats. One thing to notice is that any linear recurrence admits a `O(log n)` solution.

Answer (score 1):

As the value of `n` is very high, integer overflow is obvious.

Follow the following rules for **modular arithmetic**:

1. **Addition:** (a+b)%m = (a%m + b%m)%m
2. **Subtraction:** (a-b)%m = (a%m + b%m + m)%m
3. **Multiplication:** (a*b)%m = (a%m * b%m)%m
4. **Exponential:** Use loop.

Example: For a^n, use a = (a%m * a%m)%m, n number of times.

For larger values of `n`, use the python's **pow(x, e, m)** function to get the modulo calculated which takes a lot less time.

Comment: this will be good only for small `n` in `a^n` for big exponents you need power by squaring ...

Comment: Correct @Spektre.

Comment: However OP clarified that in `a^b` the `a` is `float` !!! so either fixed or floating point power is needed ... I would go for fixed as that one can be done on integers without probems with arbitrary precision log,exp which are in my opinion the cause of overflow

Comment: @Spektre but OP is using a fundamentally wrong approach for the original problem, neither floating point power nor fixed point power would solve it

Answer (score 1):

A working way to calculate it with integers only is to develop your expression using the binomial expansion. After rearranging it a bit, we get a rather easy way to calculate it, with an almost identical formula for terms of even and odd power:

```
def form(n, mod):
    cnk = 1
    total = 0
    for k in range(n+1):
        term = cnk * 3**k * 17**((n-k)//2)
        if (n-k) % 2 == 1:
            term *= 5
        total += term
        cnk *= (n-k)
        cnk //= (k+1)

        
    return (total // (2**n)) #% mod
```

We can compare it to your original formula to check the results:

```
from math import sqrt

def orig(n):
    return ((((5+ sqrt(17)) * ((3 + sqrt(17)) ** n)) - ((5-sqrt(17))* ((3 - sqrt(17)) ** n)))/((2 ** (n+1)) * sqrt(17)))

for n in range(20):
    print(n, orig(n), form(n, mod))
```

Output:

```
0 1.0000000000000002 1
1 4.0 4
2 14.000000000000002 14
3 50.0 50
4 178.0 178
5 634.0000000000001 634
6 2258.0 2258
7 8042.0 8042
8 28642.000000000004 28642
9 102010.00000000001 102010
10 363314.0 363314
11 1293962.0000000002 1293962
12 4608514.0 4608514
13 16413466.000000004 16413466
14 58457426.00000001 58457426
15 208199210.00000003 208199210
16 741512482.0000001 741512482
17 2640935866.000001 2640935866
18 9405832562.0 9405832562
19 33499369418.000004 33499369418
```

It is "rather" fast for not to large values of n (tested on an old machine):

```
#%timeit form(1000, mod)
# 9.34 ms ± 87.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#%timeit form(10000, mod)
# 3.79 s ± 14.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#%timeit form(20000, mod)
# 23.6 s ± 37.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

For the last test, before taking the modulo, we have a 11033 digits number.

The main problem with this approach is that, as we have to divide by 2**n at the end, we can't take the modulo at each step and keep the numbers we manipulate small.

Using the suggested approach with matrix multiplication (I hadn't seen the link to the recursion formula when I started with this answer, too bad!) will allow you to do this, though.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your time and concentration.

Comment: I am going to go with matrix multiplication