# How to work with very large number like 100 digits or so?

Tags: python

I want to do arithmetic operations like adding two 100 digit long number then how can I perform using the programming language like python or any other as long long int can support till 20 digits max.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538551/handling-very-large-numbers-in-python

Comment: You use the `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `**`, etc. symbols. Python supports an arbitrarily long number out of the box as part of [PEP237](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/)- just plug and play.

Comment: If you need more performance on truly huge integers, consider using gmpy, which does things like FFT for multiplication whereas the stdlib uses Karatsuba.