# Sliding window algorithm to calculate the list of all k-element contiguous subarray products of an array modulo p

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sliding-window, modular-arithmetic

I have an array of `n` positive integers. I want to calculate a list of all contiguous subarray products of size `k` modulo `p`. For instance for the following array:

`a = [3, 12, 5, 2, 3, 7, 4, 3]`

with `k = 3` and `p = 12`, the ordered list of all `k`-sized contiguous subarray products will be:

`k_products = [180, 120, 30, 42, 84, 84]`

and modulo `p` we have:

`k_products_p = [0, 0, 6, 6, 0, 0]`

we can easily compute `k_products` using a sliding window. All we have to do is to compute the product for the first `k`-sized subarray and then compute the next elements of `k_product` using the following formula:

`k_product[i] = k_product[i - 1] * a[i + k] / a[i - 1]`

and after forming the whole list, we can compute `k_product[i] % p` for each `i` to get `k_product_p`. That's it. `O(n)` complexity is pretty good.

But if the elements of `a[i]` are big, the elements of k_product may overflow, and thus we cannot compute `k_product_p`. Plus, we cannot, for example do the following:

`k_product[i] = ((k_product[i - 1] % p) * (a[i + k] % p) / (a[i - 1] % p)) % p  // incorrect`

So is there a fast algorithm to do this? Note that `p` is not necessarily prime and it is also not necessarily coprime to the elements of `a`.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, there will be no overflow in python, but working with very big numbers will be time-consuming.

Comment: in some instances it may help to first divide and then multiply

Comment: In Python, there should be no `overflow` problem, I believe.  Some posts about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538551/handling-very-large-numbers-in-python

Comment: You are right. But the complexity will be quite messy I think. @DanielHao

Comment: Why is that? ~ `...complexity will be quite messy`?  You can still use sliding window tech. to  solve it. Right?

Comment: yes, but python might have to deal with 100 digit numbers. I don't think it would be a fast solution. Memory is another issue. @DanielHao

Comment: Ah ... so you imply there is a time requirement or constraint.  But your OP did not say that...

Comment: Why does it have to be a sliding window algorithm?  That's not really a good way to solve this problem.

Comment: You also cannot do `/ a[i - 1]` if `a[i - 1]` is 0.

Comment: Consider user1984's comment - it will certainly help you with the big numbers problem.  If you modulo all your numbers first, you will get the same result for k_products_p.   You'll also need to be careful of what גלעד ברקן cautions.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the elements are all positive integers, so there is no 0 in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a sliding window algorithm, but it is a simple and effective way to solve this problem in O(n) time without any division:

Let A be your original array.  We will imagine that there is a "mark" on every kth element of A -- elements A[0], A[k], A[2k], etc.  This ensures that every k-length window in A will contain *exactly one* mark.

Now, make two new arrays B and C, such that:

- In array B, each element B[i] will contain the product (mod p) of A[i] and all following elements up to *but not including* the next mark.  If A[i] is marked, then B[i] = 1.  You can calculate this in a single pass backward from i=n-1 to i=0.
- In array C, each element C[i] will contain the product (mod p) of A[i] and all preceding elements down to *and including* the previous mark.  If A[i] is marked, then C[i] = A[i].  You can calculate this in a single pass forward from i=0 to i=n-1.

Now, you can easily calculate the complete product of any k-length window in constant time, because the product of any window from A[i]...A[i+k-1] is just **B[i] * C[i+k-1]**.  Remember that there is exactly one mark inside the window.  B[i] is the product of the elements before the mark, and C[i+k-1] is the product of the marked element and the elements after it.

Comment: That's inspiring and educational. Thanks for posting!

Comment: I never thought of any algorithm other than sliding window. But this one was simple and genius. Thank you!