# How convert int to BigInteger (Python)

Tags: python, integer, bigint, asyncpg, aiogram

How do I convert int to BigInteger in Python?

I can't find anything like this on the net for python. I need to convert int to BigInteger in order to compare via Sqlalchemy ORM with the value in the database (telegram_id are registered via models with the bigint type)

error:

```
asyncpg.exceptions.UndefinedFunctionError: operator does not exist: bigint !~~* unknown
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "BigInteger" in python is called "long". You might want to checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538551/handling-very-large-numbers-in-python) post.

(I would have answered as a comment since this is not really a solution but I can't comment yet because of my low reputation)